# Should the BLL validate the same things as the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my web application I have the following layers:

- UI

  - Controllers, ViewModels, Views
- BLL

  - Services
- DAL

  - Repositories
- Models

In my UI layer I use DataAnnotations on ViewModels to validate input. The controllers communicate with services to do something with it like registering a new user. My question is: should I validate the same things in the service that the DataAnnotations already did on the ViewModels like username, password and email validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this service layer is intended to be reused outside of your ASP.NET MVC application, then you should validate. If not, then it might not be strictly necessary to do the **same** validation. On your service layer you should validate business requirements such as for example *the specified username already exists* or *you cannot wire $3000 to account X because you have only $2000 in your current account*.

Answer (score 0):

Validating again in your service layer again can help "future proof" your application if it's going to be used elsewhere, like adding a web service to your application for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate all data coming to your service. It may happen that UI layer performs the same validation (or even shares code to do so).

Note that some validations (i.e. "email is real", "user created successfuly") can only be performed on service.